# Is it possible to permanently add directories to the default ld search path?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ld

I'm attempting to install a library that will be used generally on this node. Currently the library is installed in a location that includes it's version name /opt/sample-x.y.z/lib/libsample.so. Ideally I'd like to be able to update the library, change the sys configs and not bother other devs with needing to change paths on trivial changes. I've added the library directory to the /etc/ld.so.conf.d/sample.conf and run ldconfig, but this only seems to affect loading not linking.

When I run `ldconfig -v | grep sample`, I correctly see libsample.so.

However, whenever I run `ld -lsample --verbose`, it fails to find the library. In the verbose output, it details the directories that it searches and the one I added with ldconfig isn't there. As a workaround, I tested adding a symlink to the library in /usr/lib and ld was able to find it.

Are there other ways to add the library to the default linker path? Ideally I'm looking for a config file that I can modify similar to the one for loading.

If it matters, the node is a Centos7 node.

Comment: How about just installing the library in the default search path to begin with?  In particular, in /usr/lib64 (for 64-bit CentOS 7)?

Comment: So what does your `sample.conf` look like atm?

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's a possibility. I'd just have to write wrapper scripts on top of the provided installer because it doesn't put everything I need in the appropriate locations by default. If something similar to the ld.so.conf scripts worked, it seemed a quicker option and at this point it is more of a general knowledge question.

Comment: @tink It is pretty basic. The actual software has libs in a couple locations, but each location is captured in the file on a unique line. No trailing / on an of the lines. Carrying on with this example it is just /opt/sample-x.y.z/lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The paths that ld uses during the linking phase are configured via scripts which are pulled into ld during its build process. There isn't a way to update these after ld is built. There are other questions and answers related to accomplishing this for GCC specifically which seem to involve the LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. That solution, however, is gcc specific.

Comment: This is the best I was able to discover during my own reading. I wanted to document the negative response in case someone stumbles across the question in the future. I'll be happy to change the selected answer in the future if someone is able to find a solution.